# Nested Json still showing in my pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a nested json in file form in which I want to normalize. This code places the data in a DataFrame; however, I have a column with json still in it.

For example. I have a column called 'Hours' and the code below is showing. How would you approach this?

```
None
{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '8:0-18:30', 'Wednesday': '8:0-18:30', 'Thursday': '8:0-18:30', 'Friday': '8:0-18:30', 'Saturday': '8:0-14:0'}
{'Monday': '8:0-22:0', 'Tuesday': '8:0-22:0', 'Wednesday': '8:0-22:0', 'Thursday': '8:0-22:0', 'Friday': '8:0-23:0', 'Saturday': '8:0-23:0', 'Sunday': '8:0-22:0'}
{'Monday': '7:0-20:0', 'Tuesday': '7:0-20:0', 'Wednesday': '7:0-20:0', 'Thursday': '7:0-20:0', 'Friday': '7:0-21:0', 'Saturday': '7:0-21:0', 'Sunday': '7:0-21:0'}
{'Wednesday': '14:0-22:0', 'Thursday': '16:0-22:0', 'Friday': '12:0-22:0', 'Saturday': '12:0-22:0', 'Sunday': '12:0-18:0'}
{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '6:0-22:0', 'Wednesday': '6:0-22:0', 'Thursday': '6:0-22:0', 'Friday': '9:0-0:0', 'Saturday': '9:0-22:0', 'Sunday': '8:0-22:0'}
```

```
This is my method to load the file into a pandas dataframe

data = []
for line in data_file:
    data.append(json.loads(line))
checkin_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_file.close()

The code below got me the results you see.

for attribute_data in new_df:
    print(attribute_data)
```

Comment: This looks like a regular Python dictionary, so I don't think you need to involve JSON anymore if it's already in a dataframe. You can access elements using commands like `df[Hours][0]["Monday"]` or `df[Hours][0].get("Monday","")` for when "Monday" isn't a key, but the big question is what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: please write `print(df.head(5))` and paste the output to the question.